# Change Title in Nav-Bar From Ctrl

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am new to ionic in my app what i want to do is change the title of the app page based on the page the user is on.  Example if the user is on the home page it should say **Home** at the top if they are on another page it should say **Another** at the top.

Each page has it's own controller, i have created a parent controller for my application called `AppCtrl` and put that on the pane:

```
<ion-pane ng-controller="AppCtrl">
</ion-pane>
```

This is my AppCtrl:

```
 // Root Controller
        .controller("AppCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope) {

            // Adding Sum Property To Array Prototype
            Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
                var total = 0
                for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
                    total += this[i][prop]
                }
                return total
            }

            $scope.title = {
                name: '',
                icon: ''
            };

            // Function To Change Pane Title
            $rootScope.changeTitle = function(name, icon) {

                $rootScope.title = {
                    name: name,
                    icon: icon
                };

                $rootScope.$broadcast('TITLE_UPDATED', $rootScope.title);

            }

            $scope.$on('TITLE_UPDATED', function(event, title) {
                $scope.title = {
                    name: title.name,
                    icon: title.icon
                };
            })

        })
```

This is my Home Controller:

```
 // Home View Controller
        .controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope) {

            // Setting Title
            $scope.changeTitle('Home', 'ion-home');

        })
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- custom css styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.ctrls.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mtgh">

<ion-pane ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <!-- </header + navbar> -->
    <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable bar-header-shadow has-header">
                <ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-back-button>

                <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                    </button>

                    <h1 class="title">
                        <i class="{{ title.icon }}"></i> {{ title.name }}
                    </h1>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>

            <ion-nav-view name="content">
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

        <h1 class="title">
            <img src="img/logo-94x35.png" alt="Starter" title="Starter">
        </h1>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">
                    <img src="img/logo-94x35.png" alt="Starter" title="Starter">
                </h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" ng-click="login()">
                        Login
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" href="#/app/search">
                        Search
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" href="#/app/browse">
                        Browse
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item menu-close="" href="#/app/playlists">
                        Playlists
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
    <!-- </header> -->

    <!-- <footer> -->
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Starter</h1>
    </ion-footer-bar>
    <!-- </footer> -->

</ion-pane>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To do what? And how exactly would i use it?

Comment: I want to set a custom name not use the state or location name / path.

Comment: I see nothing there that allows me to set a custom title for my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the changeTitle function to live in your run method so it is globally setup. The following plunker shows this using just title.name, you'd just need to replace your title elements in your main nav.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nx9eLhYq62COLaFd21qT?p=preview

You'll notice too that I got rid of the local scope title references in the controller, this is because of the way scopes are layered in AngularJS, if it can't find an item in the current child scope it will look up the chain, which in this case is directly to rootScope.

Code for reference:

*app.js:*

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    template: '<div><a href="#/home">Go Home</a></div>'
  }).
  when('/home', {
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    template: '<div>At Home <a href="#/">Go Back</a></div>'
  })
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.changeTitle = function(name, icon) {
    $rootScope.title = {
      name: name,
      icon: icon
    };
  } 
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.changeTitle('Main', 'ion-settings');
});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.changeTitle('Home', 'ion-home');
})
```

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{{title.name}}</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>{{title.name}}</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: One comment about broadcast, because this is in the main loop and is a direct effect on a scope element, you shouldn't need to broadcast a change as it will directly update any bound element which {{title.name}} is.

Comment: Wow okay, the plunkr doesn't seem to be showing though.

Comment: I updated the plunker link and I'm able to get to it from multiple browsers so it should be usable now.

Comment: Oh and you'll notice I'm applying controllers from the router, you should transition to that as it will give you more granular control as you move around the nav. A version of the plunker with your nav menu is at http://plnkr.co/edit/aVnQyTuZBGz1crnXET5l?p=preview